# Is it possible to have common configuration in DSC configuration block?

Tags: dsc

I'm wondering if it's possible in configuration block which contains 2 nodes to have also configuration which will be common between 2 nodes without duplicating code (some sort of `include` configuration)
Something like below

```
Configuration {
   Node One {
      ...
      $commonResources
   }
   Node Two
   {
      ...
      $commonResources
   }

   $commonResouces = 
   {
   File CommonFile
   {
      
   }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Configuration {
   Node $AllNodes.NodeName {
      $commonResources
      File CommonFile
      {
      
      }
   }
   Node One {
      ...
   }
   Node Two
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

All common configurations can be placed under the $AllNodes.NodeName node. All configurations under this node will be on all nodes. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. It compiled first MOF file (All Nodes configuration) and then overwrote it on dedicated configuration.

Comment: I would need some more info or the complete configuration to see what the problem is. So if you can give that or try to explain what it is that you are trying to do, i can help you further.

Comment: This works. Any idea how to setup dependencies between resources in such cases between dedicated and common resources? Normal `Dependson = '[Type]resource'` did not work